# Definite integral involving Legendre Polynomial

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

Does anyone know the answer to the following definite integral:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}P_{\ell}(\cos\theta)\sin^{k}\theta\, d\theta$

for $k\geq1$, where $P_{\ell}(x)$ is the $\ell$-th Legendre polynomial? What about for $k=2$?

Comment: May we assume $\ell$ is a non-negative integer?

Comment: I haven't got a complete answer, but have you considered using beta functions? There are formulae for derivatives of Legendre polynomials, and

$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^k\theta d\theta=B\left(\frac{k+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right),
$$

so maybe you could combine this with an integration by parts and possibly some arguments about symmetry and even-or-odd functions?

Comment: (by which I mean symmetries of the function $\sin^k\theta$)